# Can Ecto cast a list to an integer array in a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

Using PostgreSQL and Ecto, I'm trying to select a list of rows by id in the order specified.

In `psql`, this query gets items with ids 4, 2, 1, and 4 again, in that exact order.

```
SELECT items.id, items.name
FROM items
-- unnest expands array values into rows
INNER JOIN unnest(ARRAY[4,2,1,4]) AS item_id
ON items.id = item_id
```

Eg:

```
 id |     name
----+---------------
  4 | Toast Mitten
  2 | Pickle Juicer
  1 | Horse Paint
  4 | Toast Mitten
```

How can I translate this into an Ecto query?

Answer (score 0):

### Using a join fragment

```
  defp specified_sort(query, ordered_ids) do
    from q in query,
      join: i in fragment("unnest(?::int[])", ^ordered_ids),
      on: q.id == i
  end
```